# Как реализовать вывод двух наибольших дат?

Tags: c#

Необходимо вывести две наибольшие даты из вводимых трех. Но я вообще не понимаю принцип работы DateTime и Compare

Вот что у меня пока получилось:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Введите дату в формате: {0:d}", new DateTime(2018, 1, 7));
    Console.Write("1) ");
    var first = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("2) ");
    var second = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("3) ");
    var third = Console.ReadLine();
    var result = DateTime(first, second, third);
    Console.WriteLine("Результат: ");
    Console.WriteLine(result.Item1);
    Console.WriteLine(result.Item2);
    Console.Read();
}
private static (string, string) DateTime(string str1, string str2, string str3)
{
    string BI = "Они равны", TI = "";
    if (String.Compare(str2, str1) > 0 && String.Compare(str2, str3) > 0)
        return (str1, str3);
    else if (String.Compare(str1, str2) > 0 && String.Compare(str1, str3) > 0)
        return (str2, str3);
    else if (String.Compare(str3, str2) > 0 && String.Compare(str3, str1) > 0)
        return (str2, str1);
    else
        return (BI, TI);
}
```

Comment: Необходимо вывести две наибольшие даты из вводимых трех. Но я вообще не понимаю принцип работы DateTime и Compare@AK

Comment: Вы вводите строки. Нужно перевести строки в дату и сравнивать даты, а не строки. Используйте `DateTime.Parse()`. Далее нужно понять, какой алгоритм вам больше подойдёт -- либо объявить массив из N дат (сортируем массив по убыванию и выводим M первых значений) или вы хотите руками сравнивать first, second и third -- и вообще в программировании стараются обобщать алгоритм. У вас учебное задание и нельзя пользоваться массивами дат?

Comment: @user317108 [DateTime.Parse](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse)

Comment: Да, задание учебное, но пользоваться можно чем угодно, да вот только я прочитав ваше сообщение про сортировку массива дат, точно так реализовать не смогу. Как это вообще сделать то? @AK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Алгоритм:

1. Вводим массив из datesToRead дат, каждую дату из строки переводим в дату
2. Сортируем массив
3. Выводим первые showMax дат

Что-то в духе:

```
void Main()
{
    int datesToRead = 3;
    int showMax = 2;

    var data = this.ReadDates(datesToRead);
    Array.Sort(data);
    this.ShowMaxes(data, showMax);
}

// Define other methods and classes here

public DateTime[] ReadDates(int datesToRead = 3)
{
//  return new DateTime[] {
//      System.DateTime.Today.AddDays(-2),
//      System.DateTime.Today.AddDays(-5),
//      System.DateTime.Today.AddDays(-3),
//  };
    var result = new DateTime[datesToRead];
    var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ru-RU");
    var styles = DateTimeStyles.None;
    Console.WriteLine($"Введите даты ({datesToRead} шт).");
    for(var i = 0; i < datesToRead; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Ввведите дату № {i+1}");
        var dt = Console.ReadLine();
        result[i] = DateTime.Parse(dt, culture, styles);
    }
    return result;
}

void ShowMaxes(DateTime[] data, int showMax)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < showMax; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(data[i]);
    }
}
```

Сортировку по убыванию посмотрите в [учебнике](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=netcore-1.1) как делать (хинт - через IComparer), обработку exception в случае некорректных дат если понадобится - тоже сами. Чтобы уж совсем не делать всю домашку за вас.